# strip remaining portion after one word in a string

Tags: javascript, string, groovy, cpu-word, strip

I need to strip remaining portion after the word "STOP" in a string

Example 1:

Input:  "Hello STOP CAN NOT BE"

output: "CAN NOT BE"

Example 2:

Input :  "OK PLEASE  STOP  THERE"

Output : `THERE"

Can somebody help this in JavaScript or grooovy script ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you made your attempt? What went wrong, and in what way?

Comment: Why is this JavaScript and groovy?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
var input = "Hello STOP CAN NOT BE"
var output = input.split("STOP").pop().trim();
console.log(output);
```

EDITED: Added trim() thanks @Roko C. Buljan

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe it has to do with you just providing an answer a users question who didn't show an attempt at solving their own problem

Comment: @snb or simply cause the returned string in not the expected one.

Comment: P.S: you might want to .pop().trim() ?

Comment: I'm still unsure as to exactly what part OP wants, it's a little ambiguous, thanks for feedback